# kernel code native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath function

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm, spinlock, paravirtualization

In the kernel code, I cannot find the definition of the native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath function, __pv_queued_spin_lock_slowpath is the same, where are these functions defined? I searched all the kernel code, but in vain

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath` is in "kernel/locking/qspinlock.c", using a macro to change the name of `queued_spin_lock_slowpath` to `native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath` when `CONFIG_PARAVIRT_SPINLOCKS` is defined:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_PARAVIRT_SPINLOCKS
#define queued_spin_lock_slowpath   native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath
#endif
```

…

```
void __lockfunc queued_spin_lock_slowpath(struct qspinlock *lock, u32 val)
{
```

---

The definition of `__pv_queued_spin_lock_slowpath` is also in "kernel/locking/qspinlock.c" using the same renaming macro trick with a twist — The "qspinlock.c" file includes itself once more, using a guard macro `_GEN_PV_LOCK_SLOWPATH` to avoid infinite recursive inclusion:

```
#if !defined(_GEN_PV_LOCK_SLOWPATH) && defined(CONFIG_PARAVIRT_SPINLOCKS)
#define _GEN_PV_LOCK_SLOWPATH
```

…

```
#undef  queued_spin_lock_slowpath
#define queued_spin_lock_slowpath   __pv_queued_spin_lock_slowpath

#include "qspinlock_paravirt.h"
#include "qspinlock.c"
```

…

```
#endif
```